# Quotients of the ring of Laurent polynomials in one variable

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I am trying to understand quotients of the ring $R=k[X,X^{-1}]$, where $k$ is a finite field.

I note that $R$ is a PID since it is the localization of a PID; namely $k[X]$ localized at $\{1,X,X^2,\ldots\}.$

The units in $R$ are precisely the elements of the form $aX^r$ where $a \in F^\times$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Hence every proper ideal of $R$ is generated by a **unique** element of the form

$$f=a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+X^n.$$

where $a_0\neq 0.$ This affords a method of enumerating the ideals of $R$.

I now wish determine the size of the quotient ring $R/(f)$ and this is where I get a bit stuck.

I think that the (ordinary) polynomials in $X$ of degree $<n$ form a complete set of residue classes.

If this is correct, then $|R/(f)|=|k|^n.$

Is this right? If not, I would be very glad of a push in the right direction!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to note that $k[X,X^{-1}]=k[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ and that you're taking a quotient of this quotient. Following what you said we may assume the polynomial we're taking the quotient by is of the form $X^n+a_1 X^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n$ and in this case the quotient is $k[X,Y]/(f(X),XY-1)$ which is the same as first taking the quotient by $f(X)$ and then inverting $X$. Note that from $X^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i X^i$ you can express $X^{-1}$ in terms of $X^{n-1},\ldots,X,1$, then $X^{-2}$ in terms of $X^{-1},\ldots,X^{n-2}$ and so on. So indeed we get a $k$-basis formed by $X^k$ with $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.